# Internal compiler error when UseDotNetNativeToolchain is true

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, win-universal-app, codenameone, windows-10-universal

I have a UWP app that compiles successfully if I have `UseDotNetNativeToolchain` off.  But when I turn it on, it gives me the cryptic error:

> Internal compiler error: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object. UWPApp  C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets   887 Build

This is all it gives me.  What could be causing this?  How can I drill down on this.

Using VS2015

Here is the full build output in case that helps:

https://gist.github.com/shannah/e24fe8456313fb9ad98577c9a812f357

Comment: The .NET Native compiler crashed, that happens.  You first need to check if a Hello World app can compile, if not then it is an environmental problem.  If it survives then comment chunks out in your source code to narrow down the trouble.  Calling Microsoft Support would be wise.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Did Anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Yes.  I added the solution as an answer just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to disable optimization in a few assemblies I was using in the Default.rd.xml file.  E.g.

```xml
 <Assembly Name="IKVM.OpenJDK.Core" Dynamic="All" DoNotInline="true" DoNotOptimize="true"/>
```

Comment: How did you find out what assemblies to set the `DoNotInline="true" DoNotOptimize="true"` for?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but I think I did this for all of the assemblies in my project. You may be able to get by without doing such a broad stroke through trial and error.