# Xamarin UWP release mode Error - ILT005 returned exit code 1

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, active-directory

I am developing Xamarin UWP app for Active Directory login. This application builds well in Debug mode but in Release mode it is throwing below error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ NuGetPackagesFallback\ microsoft.net.native.compiler\ 1.7.3\ tools\ x86\ilc\Tools\Gatekeeper.exe  @"I:...\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\gkargs.rsp"' returned exit code 1   SampleWinApp

I am using VS 2017 and had installed two Nuget packages

1) Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Version - 3.19.2
2) Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform Version - 6.0.8

I have been facing this problem since many days and had tried to search for solution on almost every site but did not find any proper solution.

Any help will highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Internal compiler error when UseDotNetNativeToolchain is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655045/internal-compiler-error-when-usedotnetnativetoolchain-is-true) ... the answer there suggests disabling optimizations for some assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ NuGetPackagesFallback\ microsoft.net.native.compiler\ 1.7.3\ tools\ x86\ilc\Tools\Gatekeeper.exe @"I:...\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\gkargs.rsp"' returned exit code 1 SampleWinApp

Please try to uncheck `Compile with .Net Native tool chain` option in project property. It will work.

[image]

Comment: Isn't .NET Native required in order to publish a UWP app? Guidance [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx) shows enabling `UseDotNetNativeToolchain`.

Comment: Nico: broken link 404 :(

Comment: This doesnt worl for me if I select Release mode. It builds fine if I am debug mode.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Link broken

Comment: Iink broken? could you explain more?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT The link you posted above (document) is broken. It sends to a 404 page. Can anyone confirm if this fix works?

Comment: Ok, here is [new link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/#troubleshooting) that is Universal Windows Platform troubleshooting .